# Kubernetes cluster as pubsub push subscriber

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-kubernetes-engine

If I want a Google Cloud Kubernetes cluster to act as a subscriber for a pubsub push notification, what is the best way to actually receive the notification on a node?

I assume I need to specify a load balancer as the end point for the subscription, but could\should I use nginx on each pod to receive the messages? Or something else?

Any patterns or examples available?

Comment: nodes are managed virtual machines, all your changes will be lost on scaling  or updating the cluster. are you sure you mean nodes?

Comment: Refer to this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49480116/gke-pubsub-messages-between-pods-with-push-subscribers) which may help you. Also, clarify the question if referring to the node. Also, You can use [nginx ingress](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke).

Comment: Yes I mean pod, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, that other thread almost answers the question. I'm just looking for an example of GKE ingress for pubsub push notifications, and how to actually listen on port 443. Is ngnix a valid pattern to receive the push notifications and run some custom code?

Comment: I am not able to find an example for your use case. However [this](https://hackernoon.com/setting-up-nginx-ingress-on-kubernetes-2b733d8d2f45) may help you. You can define the container ports for the ngnix-ingress controller and use as per the requirement.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

If you're referring to Cloud Pub/Sub, you can't have your application get a HTTP request when there's a new message on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic. That's simply not how Cloud Pub/Sub works.

Your application needs to listen to the messages using Cloud Pub/Sub API client.

There's a sample Pub/Sub application on GKE here: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform But it will not expose a load balancer and get the messages via an Ingress as you wanted.

---

By "pubsub", if you are referring to general "publish-subscribe pattern" in general, you can just create a multi-replica application, put them behind a load balancer (or Ingress), and have the message queue call your endpoint when there's a message.

But I'm not sure why this is a question in the first place, as I just described a simple load balanced app.

Comment: I see the docs about the [Push Subscription](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push), which seems to allow you to get an HTTP call with every new Pub/Sub message without needing a Pub/Sub SDK. Or do I misunderstand what this is for?

Comment: You understand it right but your question has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: In your first paragraph you say that it's not possible to get an HTTP call whenever there is a new message on a Pub/Sub topic. But as far as I understand the Push subscription is doing exactly this.